# Loop to return the sum of integers

Tags: python, python-2.7, while-loop

I am stuck on a question where I have to return the sum of all numbers within 10 seeds of the number entered by the user (inclusive). For instance, if the number was 1, it would be 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9 = 45. So far I have:

```
def temp(n1):

    seed = n1
    counter = 0 
    while counter < 9:
         n1 += 1
         counter+= 1
return n1
```

I would appreciate any explanation as to why my code does not work and help in fixing my code.

Comment: python 2.7 I believe

Comment: Please explain the actual problem clearly. Are you getting an error or your program produces incorrect result?

Answer (score 2):

Answer of @Majora320 is correct and explains why your code does not work. But  a liitle more concise solution would be

```
def temp(n):
   seed = 10
   return ((seed * (seed-1))/2) + (n-1)

print temp(1)
print temp(10)
print temp(11)
print temp(12)
```

**OP**

```
45
54
55
56
```

Basically it take advance of mathemetical equation seed*(seed-1)/2 to add consecutive number starting from 1. But since your base no can be greater then 1 I have added (n-1) to adjust that offset.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you are adding 1 each time, where you should be adding the counter plus 1 (since you should be incrementing be one *more* each time):

```
def temp(n1):
    n1 -= 1                        <-- HERE
    counter = 0 

    while counter < 9:
         n1 += counter + 1         <-- HERE
         counter += 1

    return n1
```

Also, you need to subtract one from n1 initially to make up for the fact that we should be adding 0 at the 0th iteration.

On a side note, you don't need the variable `seed`, I assume this was from previous designs of the algorithm.

This generates the correct results as you would expect:

```
>>> temp(1)
45
```

An alternative way would be to use `for` and `range`. A solution for the "every other number" problem using `for` and `range` appears here:

```
def temp(n1):
    n1 -= 1

    for counter in range(1, 11, 2): # We use 11 instead of 9 because we want to *stop* on 11 (9 is inclusive)
         n1 += counter

    return n1
```

Comment: This works, thanks! Could you clarify a bit on the "n1+=counter+1" line? I've never had to code where both sides had +'s and I think that's confusing me.

Comment: @Jessica The second `+` is being evaluated first, so it comes out to `n1 += (counter + 1)`, where `counter + 1` is being added to `n1`.

Comment: Thanks! last question, could you write how the code would change if I had to get the sum of every other number?

Comment: As in `1 + 3 + 5 + 7`?

Comment: yep, that exactly but up to 9 if it was 1. 1+3+5+7+9

Comment: @Jessica Edited to add a solution